# Tab Bar mysteriously disappears?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

Attached are two images. The first shows my current main.storyboard, and the second shows my problem when I run the app. I have a tab bar controller that has two tabs. On the first tab there is a button. When pressed, the button goes to another view controller with content. At the top is a Navigation bar with a back button. After viewing content, I press the back button, and am back on the original page with the button, but the tab bar is missing. I have seen a few answered questions, but it appears they made their tab bar in the view controller instead of the storyboard. Another says that I should never return to a previous view unless I use an unwind segue. Is this true? If so, how do I set up an unwind segue. If not, how do I fix this problem otherwise? Thank you.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmX2.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7slt5.png

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the wiring of your ViewControllers. You have probably embedded your `UITabBarController` inside the `UINavigationController` and not the other way around.

A correct layout looks like this in Interface Builder :

[image: Layout in Interface Builder]

To reproduce:

- In Interface Builder drop a `UITabBarController`. This will come with 2 `UIViewController`'s already wired in.
- Pick one of the `UIViewController`'s (let's call it `VController1`) and click on Editor / Embed in / Navigation Controller. This wires the `VController1` to live inside a `UINavigationController` that is inside the `UITabBarController`
- Add a 3rd `UIViewController` next to `VController1` Let's call it `VController3`
- Wire in a segue between `VController1` and `VController3`, for example with a button.

I hope that's clear enough

Comment: I will certainly try it out.

Comment: How do I add a title to the navigation controller?

Comment: on VController1 write : self.title = "My title", same for vController2

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very inexperienced. Where do I put this code?

Comment: On VCController1.swift and VCController3.swft, You can put it on the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Try Linking the button in your viewcontroller (other than the views of the tabbed bar controller) with the tabbed bar controller. Create a segue that links the button with the controller of the tabbed bar application